'Disconnected session' when running from IDE
I just got the sparse error message 'Disconnected session' after pressing F9 to compile and run a 64-bit VCL app in Delphi 12.1.
Clearing the watch list as suggested here did not help **
Does anyone know what is disconnected, and how to prevent this error?
FWIW:

The watches are on variables from a form that is not open in the IDE. That form has a breakpoint but I'm not executing (thus loading) it.
It may have been a mouse over on a variable in the IDE wanting to display its value ('ToolTip Symbol Insight')

** Not to mention that I can only clear them if the app is running correctly from the IDE. I now have to kill bds.exe before every attempt, and then after an IDE restart all watches are gone (they are probably saved on normal exit only, like IDE registry settings). ;-)
